# Rails where check child has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Response` model that belongs_to `Quota`. Let's say quota has a `type` attribute that can either be `1` or `2`.

I want to do a call that's like `Response.where(quota.type == 1)`

What's the best way to achieve this? Basically getting a list of all responses where their quotas have a `type` of `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delegate name and then call it.

In Response:

```
  delegate :type, :to => :quota, :prefix => "quota"
```

(But using "type" might lead into problems, since of STI. Better pick other word for db attribute name)

And then you can simply call it:

```
Response.last.quota_type
```

Comment: It's not actually named `type`, it's `quota_type` :). Thanks for the info!